# What is storage/emulated/0? How can the file be found in google files? Android

Tags: java, android

What is storage/emulated/o?

This is my function that saves an audio file:

```
private void synthesizeTextToAudioFile(String textToSpeak) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       
        String destDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File directory = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs(); =
        }

        // Create a unique file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String audioFileName = "audio_" + timeStamp + ".mp3";
        File outputFile = new File(directory, audioFileName);

        // Synthesize text to an audio file
        speech.synthesizeToFile(textToSpeak, null, outputFile, "uniqueID");

        // Display a message with the file location
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Audio File Saved at: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Synthesizing to file is not supported on this device");
       
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find the file in google files, but I am unable to. It says the file is save in storage/emulated/0, but where is that? Is there a way that I can make a folder directly in the sdCard and then be able to open it on google files?

Comment: Your file on Android 11+ devices will not be saved to root of external storage. I see that you are not using a return value of speech.synthesizeToFile(). If it does not return false then it should have thrown an exception.